# Baofeng F8HP display setup

Tags: baofeng

On the Baofeng F8HP display, which bottom or top is the RX and TX?

Answer (score 0):

Manufacturers of other HTs with dual frequency displays may use one frequency display for TX and the other for RX, when operating "split" I suppose, but that's not how the Baofeng UV-5R family radios work.  One frequency display is the active one that is used for both transmit and receive, and the other frequency display is on stand-by.  The user switches frequency displays by pressing the A/B button.  I think something on the display is supposed to indicate which frequency display is active, but the display on my UV-5R+ isn't 100% functional since I took the radio apart, so I don't know what part of the display to refer you to.  (I have to guess which frequency display is active on my radio.)

Presumably the dual-frequency-display feature is meant to make switching from one channel or frequency to another channel or frequency quick and easy.  I don't find that purpose useful, so I use the feature another way.  I used CHIRP to configure my radio to display the alphanumeric channel name on one frequency display and the channel frequency on the other frequency display.  Then I set both frequency displays to the same channel.  In that way I can see both the name and the frequency of the channel I'm on.  (I don't memorize repeater frequencies any more now that I've named my channels, just like I don't memorize phone numbers any more now that I dial everyone from the address book in my mobile phone.)